# Renaming Column Elements of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe

I want to create a new DataFrame based upon the columns of another DataFrame, for which I would like to do the following:

1. **Data Retrieval:** Take partial strings from column elements from DataFrame1
2. **Renaming Column Elements:** Combine these strings and place into 2 new columns in DataFrame2

An example of the DataFrames can be seen below, where DataFrame1 is my actual data and the DataFrame2 is the type of data frame that I am interested in obtaining:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'BGC Name': ['Hm106_120.region001', 'MBT13_26.region001',
'MBT23_64.region001', 'MBT36_100.region001'], 'GCF No': [1813, 1813, 1883,
1887], 'Organism': ['Streptomyces sp', 'Streptomyces sp', 'Listeria sp',
'Streptomyces sp'], 'BGC Class': ['PKSI', 'NRPS', 'PSKI', 'NRPS']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'GCF': ['PKSI_GCF1813', 'NRPS_GCF1813', 'PKSI_GCF1883',
'NRPS_GCF1887'],'Genome': ['Streptomyces_sp_Hm106', 'Streptomyces_sp_MBT13',
'Listeria_sp_MBT23', 'Streptomyces_sp_MBT36']})

print("DataFrame1 (Original DataFrame)")
print(df1)
print("DataFrame2 (Desired DataFrame)")
print(df2)
```

Snapshot can be found: [[image: SnapShot of The DataFrame[1]]

The Code That I am trying to use

```
#Dataframe Copies
df1 = df1.copy() #self copy
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')
df2 = df1.copy() #copy of original dataframe
#Change Column Names
df1.columns = ['BGC', 'GCF', 'Description', 'Product Prediction', 'BiG-SCAPE class', 'Organism']
df2.columns = ['BGC', 'GCF', 'Description', 'Product Prediction', 'BiG-SCAPE class', 'Organism']
#DataFrame Manipulation
df2['GCF'] = df1['BiG-SCAPE class'].astype(str) + df2['GCF'].astype(str)
df1[['BGC','BGC2']] = df1['BGC'].str.split('_',n=1,expand=True)
df2['Genome'] = df1['Organism'].astype(str) + df1['BGC'].astype(str)
df2.set_index('GCF')
df2 = df2[['GCF','Genome']]
df2['Genome'] = df2['Genome'].str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('Unclassified','_').str.replace('__','_').str.replace('.','')
print(df1)
print("Updated table")
print(df2)
```

Comment: can you provide the snapshot of the dataframe.

Comment: @Preetham I just edited the post above :) What is on the left is what I have as input and on the right is what I desire as output

Answer (score 1):

Here, first I created the column values as a list and then assigned them to be the new dataframe's columns. However, we could do it using the columns and without creating lists. It just seems easier this way.

```py
#Initializing the new_df (df2) dataframe
import pandas as pd
new_columns =  ['GCF', 'Genome']
new_df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = new_columns)
#new_df
#df1.columns
#creating the column GCF of the new dataframe 
GCF = [str(df1['BGC Class'][i])+ '_GCF' + str(df1['GCF No'][i]) for i in range(len(df1))]
#creating the new column 'Genome' of the new dataframe
organism = [df1['Organism'][i].replace(' ', '_') for i in range(len(df1))] #substituting ' ' by '_'
BGC_name = [list(df1['BGC Name'].str.split('_'))[i][0] for i in range(len(df1))]
genome = [organism[i] + '_' + BGC_name[i] for i in range(len(df1))]
new_df['GCF'] = GCF
new_df['Genome'] = genome
```

Output:

```
    GCF             Genome
0   PKSI_GCF1813    Streptomyces_sp_Hm106
1   NRPS_GCF1813    Streptomyces_sp_MBT13
2   PSKI_GCF1883    Listeria_sp_MBT23
3   NRPS_GCF1887    Streptomyces_sp_MBT36
```

The second way in which we do not create lists and change the columns' values sort of inplace, is as following:

```py
#Initializing the new_df (df2) dataframe
import pandas as pd
new_columns =  ['GCF', 'Genome']
new  = pd.DataFrame(columns = new_columns)
#new_df
#df1.columns
BGC_name = [list(df1['BGC Name'].str.split('_'))[i][0] for i in range(len(df1))]
new['GCF'] = df1['Organism'].str.replace(' ', '_')+ '_' + BGC_name
new['Genome'] = df1['BGC Class']+ '_GCF'+ df1['GCF No'].astype('str')
#new
```

Comment: thanks very much for your input on this! Looks great and a very nice approach taking into consideration the lists. I thought it might just be simpler with the normal pandas approach, but this is much better. Thanks once again :)

Comment: @Biohacker Sure. Yes it is much simpler this way. However, the second approach is more used. Feel free to ask if there are further questions.

Comment: I wanted to follow up with another question, I don't know why but I get the following error :                                                                                                                                  `organism = [df1['Organism'][i].replace(' ', '_') for i in range(len(df1))] #substituting ' ' by '_'
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace' `                                              
I tried changing all my data columns to strings and this didn't have any effect, some of my string values are a bit off I guess, see the example.

Comment: Your [df1['Organism'] column might have some NULL values. You can check if it is true.

Comment: yeah, it's strange because I eliminated the NULL values before using this script. I don't know if it's how the strings are written... Another question, how would it be possible to remove everything from a given character? For example if I want to remove everything after the . (Example: sleC34_1.region026 or )  `rtr = line.split(";", 1)[0].rstrip() + '\n'` Sorry for all the noob questions, I'm quite new to coding still

Comment: For removing everything after for instance "1" in string "sleC34_1.region026"
```string =sleC34_1.region026
index = string.find('1')
string = string[:index]```

Comment: Thanks for the input :)